# Jenkins Bulder plugin: final List<String> is null after initialization

Tags: java, generics, jenkins

This is the sample code

```
public class HelloWorldBuilder extends Builder {

    private final String name;

    private final List<Object> logCollection = new ArrayList<Object>();

    // Fields in config.jelly must match the parameter names in the "DataBoundConstructor"
    @DataBoundConstructor
    public HelloWorldBuilder(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * We'll use this from the <tt>config.jelly</tt>.
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean perform(AbstractBuild build, Launcher launcher, BuildListener listener) {
        listener.getLogger().println("These are items in the collection!");

        String value = "Logging" + name + "(" + new Date() + ")";

        listener.getLogger().println(value);

        this.logCollection.add(value);

        for(Iterator<Object> i = this.logCollection.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
            Object item = i.next();
            listener.getLogger().println(item);
        }

        return true;
    }

    ...
}
```

Below is the error I got from Jenkins.

```
FATAL: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at demo.cd.statlogger.HelloWorldBuilder.perform(HelloWorldBuilder.java:71)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:785)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:160)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:566)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1665)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:246)
```

I don't understand why logCollection can be null since it's initialized.

**Update**
Line 71 is `this.logCollection.add(value);`

Comment: It's `this.logCollection.add(value);`, I also updated the question to include it.

Comment: this seems impossible.  Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: Yes, and `logCollection` is actually `null` on that line. I know very little about java and wonder if there is anything special I need to do.

Comment: What happens if you remove 'this.'? it's bugging me for some reason...

Comment: @SpaceCowboy I have tried that and it threw the same error.

Comment: The only reason i can think of is some weird deserialization error. Are you sure you are debugging the newest version? Clean the Project, rebuild the classes and try again.

Comment: @Absurd-Mind I also did that and it didn't work. I cleaned the project using `mvn clean` command.

Comment: Did you also clean your IDE build? This may differ from mvn, e.g. in eclipse

Comment: How to do that in eclipse? I just started using it 3 days ago.

Comment: Which Jenkins versions are you running in?

Comment: 1. select your project and hit F5 to refresh out of eclipse changes. 2. top bar-> Project -> Clean

Comment: @PeterLiljenberg I use `Jenkins ver. 1.532.3.`

Comment: Are you sure that you don't call any other method which nulls out logCollection reference?

Comment: @JakubHr I marked it as `final` so it's not possible.

Comment: @Absurd-Mind I just tried that, cleaning the project on eclipse then running `mvn clean` but it didn't help.

Comment: @Anonymous try print debugging, add a `System.out.println("logCollection: " + logCollection);` With this you can make sure that you have the latest version and show the value. Expected result: `logCollection: null`

Comment: I just tested that and it printed `logCollection: null
FATAL: null
java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: Hmm, I successfully ran the plugin code locally with Jenkins 1.532 - I'll try with 1.532.3 as well but I guess you have errors somewhere else in your plugin structure (I had to add some stuff to be able to add the build step to my project). Are you missing some configuration files or something? What does the log/output say? Are you running it with `mvm hip:run` or from Eclipse? (I tested from command line)

Comment: Last idea: Move the initialization to your constructor and add a `System.out.println` to make sure it is called

Comment: 1.532.3 worked as well (as expected): `Started by user anonymous
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building in workspace /Users/peterl/Source/3pp/fogbugz-plugin/work/jobs/test/workspace
These are items in the collection!
Loggingasd(Wed Apr 16 13:18:25 CEST 2014)
Loggingasd(Wed Apr 16 13:18:25 CEST 2014)
Finished: SUCCESS`

Comment: @PeterLiljenberg I tested it from the command line, just run `mvn hip:run`. Code is compilable and there is no problem if I remove that line, everything else works.

Comment: I also created a new project with a new class and it worked as well.

Comment: @PeterLiljenberg what did you add to the project to make it work?

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50781/discussion-regarding-question-23107050